# Run time error: cannot use struct as type ptr as argument

Tags: go-ethereum

I am attempting to do a flash loan and I have the following contract.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

import { IUniswapV2Pair } from "@uniswap/v2-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Pair.sol";
import { IUniswapV2Factory } from "@uniswap/v2-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Factory.sol";
import { IUniswapV2Router02 } from "@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";

interface IERC20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    function decimals() external view returns (uint8);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

contract ERC20Basic is IERC20 {
    string public constant name = "ERC20Basic";
    string public constant symbol = "ERC";
    uint8 public constant decimals = 18;
    mapping(address => uint256) balances;
    mapping(address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;
    uint256 totalSupply_ = 10 ether;

    constructor() {
        balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply_;
    }

    function totalSupply() public override view returns (uint256) {
        return totalSupply_;
    }

    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public override view returns (uint256) {
        return balances[tokenOwner];
    }

    function transfer(address receiver, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
        require(numTokens <= balances[msg.sender]);
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender]-numTokens;
        balances[receiver] = balances[receiver]+numTokens;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, receiver, numTokens);
        return true;
    }

    function approve(address delegate, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
        allowed[msg.sender][delegate] = numTokens;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, delegate, numTokens);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address owner, address delegate) public override view returns (uint) {
        return allowed[owner][delegate];
    }

    function transferFrom(address owner, address buyer, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
        require(numTokens <= balances[owner]);
        require(numTokens <= allowed[owner][msg.sender]);

        balances[owner] = balances[owner]-numTokens;
        allowed[owner][msg.sender] = allowed[owner][msg.sender]+numTokens;
        balances[buyer] = balances[buyer]+numTokens;
        emit Transfer(owner, buyer, numTokens);
        return true;
    }
}

contract Swap {
    event AssetSold(address sender, uint256 amount);
    event AssetBought(address sender, uint256 amount);
    event EtherReceived(address sender, uint amount);
    event LogMessage(string message);
    event LogMessages(string message, string message2);
    address private owner;
    address private _currentRouter0;
    address private _currentRouter1;
    address private _token;
    address public tokenPairedWithWeth;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
        tokenPairedWithWeth = 0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only contract owner can call this function");
        _;
    }

    function _log(string memory message) private {
        emit LogMessage(message);
    }

    function swapV1(address _tokenAddress, address _fromAddress, address _toAddress) public payable onlyOwner {
        uint256 swapAmount = address(this).balance;

        require(swapAmount > 0 , "You have to at least deposit something to start a DEX");
        IERC20 token = IERC20(_tokenAddress);
        //buy
        uint256 dexBalance = token.balanceOf(address(this));
        require(swapAmount <= dexBalance, "Not enough tokens in the reserve");
        token.transfer(_fromAddress, swapAmount);
        emit AssetBought(_fromAddress, swapAmount);
        //sell
        uint256 approvedAmt = token.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
        require(approvedAmt >= swapAmount, "Check the token allowance");
        token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), swapAmount);
        payable(_toAddress).transfer(swapAmount);
        emit AssetSold(msg.sender, swapAmount);
    }

    function swap(address token, uint256 ethToBorrow, address routerAddress0, address routerAddress1) public payable onlyOwner {
        _currentRouter0 = routerAddress0;
        _currentRouter1 = routerAddress1;
        _token = token;
        require(token != tokenPairedWithWeth, "Can't borrow ETH from the same pair as the one you're trading");
        address weth = IUniswapV2Router02(routerAddress0).WETH();
        address pairWeth = IUniswapV2Factory(IUniswapV2Router02(routerAddress0).factory()).getPair(weth, tokenPairedWithWeth);
        require(pairWeth != address(0), "This pool does not exist on router0");
        // Make sure the pools exist on both routers
        address pairAddress0 = IUniswapV2Factory(IUniswapV2Router02(routerAddress0).factory()).getPair(token, weth);
        require(pairAddress0 != address(0), "This pool does not exist on router0");
        address pairAddress1 = IUniswapV2Factory(IUniswapV2Router02(routerAddress1).factory()).getPair(token, weth);
        require(pairAddress1 != address(0), "This pool does not exist on router1");
        address token0 = IUniswapV2Pair(pairWeth).token0();
        address token1 = IUniswapV2Pair(pairWeth).token1();
        uint256 amount0 = weth == token0 ? ethToBorrow : 0;
        uint256 amount1 = weth == token1 ? ethToBorrow : 0;
        IUniswapV2Pair(pairWeth).swap(amount0, amount1, address(this), bytes("not empty"));

        _currentRouter0 = address(0);
        _currentRouter1 = address(0);
        _token = address(0);
    }

    function uniswapV2Call(address, uint256 amount0, uint256 amount1, bytes calldata) external {
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        address token0 = IUniswapV2Pair(msg.sender).token0();
        address token1 = IUniswapV2Pair(msg.sender).token1();

        IUniswapV2Router02 router0 = IUniswapV2Router02(_currentRouter0);
        IUniswapV2Router02 router1 = IUniswapV2Router02(_currentRouter1);

        require(msg.sender == IUniswapV2Factory(router0.factory()).getPair(token0, token1), "Unauthorized");

        require(amount0 == 0 || amount1 == 0, "Invalid amounts");

        path[0] = router1.WETH();
        path[1] = _token;

        IERC20 wethContract = IERC20(path[0]);
        IERC20 tokenContract = IERC20(path[1]);
        uint256 wethBorrowed = wethContract.balanceOf(address(this));
        wethContract.approve(_currentRouter1, wethBorrowed);

        // Buy Token with WETH on Router 1 (where it's cheaper)
        uint256 tokensReceived = router1.swapExactTokensForTokens(wethBorrowed, 0, path, address(this), block.timestamp)[1];

        // Sell Token for WETH on Router 0 (where it's more expensive)
        tokenContract.approve(_currentRouter0, tokensReceived);
        address path1 = path[0];
        path[0] = path[1]; // Reverse path
        path[1] = path1;
        uint256 wethReceived = router0.swapExactTokensForTokens(tokensReceived, 0, path, address(this), block.timestamp)[1];

        uint256 profit = wethReceived > wethBorrowed ? wethReceived - wethBorrowed : 0;
        require(wethReceived > wethBorrowed, "Not enough to reimburse loan");

        wethContract.transfer(msg.sender, wethBorrowed);         
        wethContract.transfer(tx.origin, profit);
    }

    function updateOwner(address _newOwner) public onlyOwner {
        owner = _newOwner;
    }

    receive() external payable {
        emit EtherReceived(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

    function getRemainingGas() public view returns (uint256) {
        return gasleft();
    }
}
```

I compile it with the following Docker command.

```
docker run -v /home/peter/Documents/crypto-projects/arbitrage-bot/contracts:/sources ethereum/solc:0.8.18 --allow-paths=/sources/solc -o /sources/abi --optimize --overwrite --abi --bin /sources/solc/Swap.sol
Compiler run successful. Artifact(s) can be found in directory "/sources/abi".
```

This is my file structure:

```
/contracts (main) $ tree
.
├── abi
│   ├── Swap.abi
│   ├── Swap.bin
├── api
│   └── Swap.go
├── sh
│   └── compile.sh
├── shell
│   ├── compile.sh
│   └── local-node.sh
├── solc
│   ├── Swap.sol
```

Then I get the following partial Go file

```
func (_Swap *SwapTransactor) Swap(opts *bind.TransactOpts, token common.Address, ethToBorrow *big.Int, routerAddress0 common.Address, routerAddress1 common.Address) (*types.Transaction, error) {
    return _Swap.contract.Transact(opts, "swap", token, ethToBorrow, routerAddress0, routerAddress1)
}
```

The problem is that in `func (_Swap *SwapTransactor) Swap` `ethToBorrow`  is `*big.Int` which forces me to borrow whole integer amounts of ETH. Which is expensive.

I attempted to fix that by changing `ethToBorrow` to a `*big.Float`.

```
func (_Swap *SwapTransactor) Swap(opts *bind.TransactOpts, token common.Address, ethToBorrow *big.Float, routerAddress0 common.Address, routerAddress1 common.Address) (*types.Transaction, error) {
    return _Swap.contract.Transact(opts, "swap", token, ethToBorrow, routerAddress0, routerAddress1)
}
```

The code compiles but I get **cannot use struct as type ptr as argument** error when I run it. I don't find a line number in the logs.

Does anyone know how to compile this contract so that `ethToBorrow` is a float or suggest how to fix this error?